# Are there any types of winds or waves that are produced just by Earth's rotation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, earth, planets

Are there any types of wind or waves caused/produced only and exclusively by Earth's rotation? Not influenced by Earth rotation, but produced solely by it?

In the case of waves, are Rossby waves [1](https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/rossby-wave.html) and Kelvin waves [2](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_wave) examples of that?

Comment: Does this include the fact that rotation results in a time-dependent temperature due to where the Sun is?  To answer your question, it's been over 16 years but I do have a vague recollection that Rossby waves result, in part, from Earth's rotation (but I would need to double-check that).  The one thing I do remember is that Rossby waves have oppositely directed group and phase speeds.

Comment: @honeste_vivere the thing is that I am looking for any kind of water current (like waves) or air currents (like air) that would be only produced hy Earth's rotation. Like, imagine that Earth was alone, with no Sun or Moon, just rotating alone, so no external influences e.g changes in temperature would exist. Assuming that water would stay somehow liquid and air in gas form, would the Earth rotation make any kind of waves or wind (even if very subtle)? Would Rossby waves form in that case?

Comment: I'd start by looking at Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, and/or Neptune first.  Their rotation seems to matter more than Earth and they have rather strong winds.  Saturn is dominated by internal heat sources, not the Sun.  Neptune and Uranus are just weird...

Comment: @honeste_vivere I was just gonna say that, that Jupiter winds are produced by its internal heat so I am not sure if Jupiter is a good example

Comment: No, Saturn's winds are driven by internal heat, not Jupiter.  Jupiter rotates extremely fast (~10 times Earth's radius but less than half the rotation period), so if rotation matters, Jupiter would show it...

Answer (score 0):

The Coriolis force (due to Earth rotation) is responsible for the general direction of winds in both hemispheres: West toward East in the northern hemisphere and the opposite direction in the Southern one.

[Coriolis effect](https://geography.name/how-does-the-coriolis-effect-influence-wind-direction-at-different-heights/)

Comment: As far as I know, the Coriolis effect influences the wind but does not cause them. I am looking for a type of wind (in the case of air) or waves (in the case of water) that are solely produced by Earth's rotation @Shaktyai

Comment: You are correct. The only non inertial effect  due to Earth's rotation is the Coriolis force which is small compared to pressure gradient and friction forces and requires the air to have a velocity: i.e. to already be wind.  So I am curious to know if there exist non inertial force driven winds.